# After deleting problem manually using query, how to make same problem occurred again in zabbix?

Tags: zabbix

As like title, i deleted a problem using query. What i expect to is that  makes the same problem happen again.

```
For example, i have an event - "eventid 1". I delete "eventid 1" at events and problem table.
I think that the same problem should be happen again due to no same problem existed in the events table.
```

But it doesn't act as i thought.

Is there a way to do that? or Is it not possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you mean, deleted from database? "we don't do that here."

Comment: Yes. like this "delete from problem where eventid = 1 && delete from events where eventid = 1".

Comment: to close a problem, just enable "manual close" in the trigger, and close it

Comment: Another question. When an event occurs, do you know how Zabbix remembers that the event occurred and manages to prevent the same event from occurring? (The event is set to occur only once)